# お茶碗の中の米粒のような大量のオブジェクトの物理演算をうまく行う方法はありますか？

Tags: unity3d

タイトルのように数百から数千個のオブジェクトを物理演算で動かす3Dコンテンツを作ろうと思っています。
標準のRigidbodyを使うと400個くらいのオブジェクトが積み重なったあたりから猛烈に処理が重くなり現実性がなさそうです。

このような状況を回避するには

- Rigidbodyのパラメータや設定を見直す
- Rigidbody (PhysX)以外の物理エンジンを使う

のどちらの方法が考えられるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

後者の **Rigidbody以外の物理エンジンを使う** のほうが良さそうに思えます。

というのは n個 の剛体を正しく扱うには少なくとも O(n^2) の計算が必要なため、
仮に1000個の米粒を扱うなら、毎フレームごとに少なくとも 100万回 の計算が必要です。
ゲームで扱うを考えると、この計算量は、まず現実的とは言えないでしょう。

ちょっと Unity には詳しくないので細かいことは言えませんが、
パーティクルで代用するなどの方法を検討したほうが良いように見受けられます。

Comment: 流れ落ちるだけなどであれば、パーティクルでもいいのですが鍋の中で米が移動するような形を想定しています。計算量の視点で考えると、物理演算の際は米と鍋のみを作用させ、米同士を別の方法で *適当に* 制御して O(n)に近づけるしかなさそうですね。

Comment: そうですね。加えて言うならば、米粒の形=当たり判定を完全な球や正方形にすると計算量は少なくできますし、もしくは米粒の一部を「群」で扱えるとガッツリ計算量を下げられるかと思います。後者は、昔似たようなことをやっていた経験から、満足の行く挙動に落としこむのが大変かもです。(ただ、うまくできたら見ているだけで楽しい物になりそうですね)

Comment: GPUをつかって計算をさせるCompute Shaderという機能もあるようです。ただプラットフォームがDirectX11限定になるみたいですが。
群で扱うというのは「見た目としては一粒一粒が制御されているけど、実際は違う」ということで「適当に」やる方向ですね。